# Export Logs From Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

So I am building a application in azure and I am using Azure Log Analytics and I am trying to find s good way for people on my team that dont have access to azure but need to be able to access the Logs. Does anyone have simple fast ways to create something like this. Good techinologies good ways to give people access to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few ways to do this:

1. You can use the ALA api to generate a home grown log portal
2. There are multiple SAS options out there

   - DataDog
   - Splunk
   - AppDynamics
3. Power Bi
4. Not specifically logs but prometheus and grafa for matrics and alerts and its dirt cheap compared to app insights

Answer (score 1):

Is using [Power BI to ingest your log analytics queries an option?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powerbi#export-query).

The caveat here would be the need to redo any potential charts and graphs however Power BI offers a lot of functionality as well as opportunities to join with other day sets.

In your scenario the trick would be using a service account credentials when publishing the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Azure Log Analytics rest api](https://dev.loganalytics.io/).

Then you can provide the authentication(it only authenticates to log analytics, not the entire azure) to the end user, and let them write query to fetch the logs; Or you can write a middle-ware, which can process the query request from end users.